# IllegalMonitorStateException on notify() call

Tags: java

I am calling the notify() method from synchronized block and I get a java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException. I am synchronized on this specific object, so I don't see where i am wrong. My code is like this:

```
public void setSynchronizer() {
    synchronized (_synchronizer) {
        _synchronizer = true;
        _synchronizer.notify();
    }       
}
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that `_synchronizer` is a `Boolean` object. When you do

```
_synchronizer = true;
```

The compiler resolves `true` as the object referred to by `Boolean.TRUE`.

If `_synchronizer` was `Boolean.FALSE` or another `Boolean` object before, then you are referring to a different object. You don't have the monitor on that object so `notify()` fails.

As stated in the comments, you shouldn't be synchronizing on a reference (object) that might change. You can change the state of the object referenced by the variable, but not the reference of the variable itself. Good place to start is to only `synchronized` on `final` variables.

Comment: This is the place where the note, that synchronizing on a mutable variable isn’t a good idea generally, should be added.

Comment: +1 "only use `synchronized` on `final` variables" is a good mantra. I've yet to find a good reason to deviate from this rule.

Comment: Thank you! Your comments helped me a lot. The problem was that the assignment "_synchronizer = true;" assigned a new object to _synchronizer, so the synchronization was not valid any more. I have changed the _syncronizer to Boolean[]. The new state is assigned to _syncronizer[0], so the object stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use a constant object for protection of the mutable one

```
Object sync = new Object();

...
synchronized (sync) 
{
    _synchronizer = true;
    sync.notify();
}

...
synchronized (sync) 
{
    sync.wait();
    if (_synchronizer) ...;
}
```